# DateFormatter returns nil with specific combination of TimeZone and Locale

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

In our app there is the issue with creating a date from string but is only reproducible with a very specific combination. Unfortunately, there is no way of getting it from the user that experienced the issue, so I decided to just go for it and try every possible combination:

```
import Foundation

var dateOnlyDateFormatter: (String, String) -> DateFormatter = { timeZoneS, localeS in
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneS)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeS)
    return formatter
}

let date = "2022-05-27"
let time = "06:15"

for timeZone in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
    for locale in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
        let dateFormatter = dateOnlyDateFormatter(timeZone, locale)
        let printDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        if printDate == nil {
            print("TimeZone: \(timeZone), Locale: \(locale)")
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
TimeZone: America/Asuncion, Locale: ar_SA
TimeZone: America/Asuncion, Locale: en_SA
```

I am not too sure what is the best way to handle this issue. Obviously our BE could return date using one specific Locale, like `en_US_POSIX`, but I have very little control over that, being a part of a much bigger older system. Has anybody experienced an issue like that?

Comment: I suggest that you add code in your `if printDate==nil` block to print the current date as a String using the same date formatter. That will let you figure out what the localized version of your date formatter produces in that time zone and locale.

Comment: My suggestion would let you figure out how the output varies for those locale/language combinations, and thus why it is failing to parse your date string. It is a fact that different locales interpret format strings differently. Thus if your goal is to be able to parse date strings in a fixed format, you should set your date formatter to the POSIX locale, as suggested by Sweeper in their excellent answer. If you're curious as to WHY the locale/language fails, my suggestion would let you understand it. If you're not curious, don't try it. Don't be rude to people who are trying to be helpful.

Comment: @DuncanC I am sorry. That was really rude of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the "[Working With Fixed Format Date Representations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter#2528261)" section of the `DateFormatter` docs, you'll find:

> For most fixed formats, you should also set the locale property to a POSIX locale ("en_US_POSIX"), and set the timeZone property to UTC.

You should probably just follow the advice here... But here's possibly why SA and the Paraguay timezone produces nil.

Further down that section, there is a link to a [technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) where this is explained in more detail. The part that is most related to your problem is:

> A user can change their calendar (using System Preferences > Language & Region > Calendar on OS X, or Settings > General > International > Calendar on iOS). In that case NSDateFormatter will treat the numbers in the string you parse as if they were in the user's chosen calendar. For example, if the user selects the Buddhist calendar, parsing the year "2010" will yield an NSDate in 1467, because the year 2010 on the Buddhist calendar was the year 1467 on the (Gregorian) calendar that we use day-to-day.

In the locale SA, the numbers of your date string seem to be interpreted using the [Islamic Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar). Take a look at today's date when formatted with en_SA and America/New_York.

```
let dateFormatter = dateOnlyDateFormatter("America/New_York", "en_SA")
let printDate = dateFormatter.string(from: .init())
print(printDate)
// 1443-10-26
```

Also take a look at the non-nil dates that is parsed by en_SA and America/New_York

```
let dateFormatter = dateOnlyDateFormatter("America/New_York", "en_SA")
let printDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
print(printDate)
// 2583-10-05 04:00:00 +0000
```

Notice that 10-05 is the first Sunday of the year 2583 (See [this calendar](https://print-a-calendar.com/2583-calendar)). If Paraguay still uses [the same DST rules](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/paraguay/asuncion?year=2022) as it does now in 2583, then it would mean that there is a DST gap transition at 2583-10-05 00:00:00, starting the DST period. The hour starting from 00:00:00 would be skipped, so 00:00:00 would not exist.

When parsing a date only, `DateFormatter` would try to set the time components to be 00:00:00 in the timezone of the formatter, but 00:00:00 does not exist, so the parsing fails.

---

In any case, just  set `locale` to posix and `timeZone` to UTC when you have set `dateFormat`.

Answer (score -1):

So if you use 'time' like this, there will be no nil values:

```
let dateOnlyDateFormatter: (String, String) -> DateFormatter = { timeZoneS, localeS in
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneS)
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeS)
            return formatter
        }

let date = "2022-05-27 06:15"
//let time = "06:15"

for timeZone in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
    for locale in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
        let dateFormatter = dateOnlyDateFormatter(timeZone, locale)
        let printDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        if printDate == nil {
           print(">>>>>>>> TimeZone: \(timeZone), Locale: \(locale)")
        } else {
           print("..... \(printDate)")
        }
    }
}
```